# Getting delimitMate to yield tex-quotes

Tags: delimiter-matching

Typing <kbd>`</kbd> with delimitMate gives ``` `` ```. But in tex files, it should produce `' . Can it be told to do so?

PS. I found that this is easy with AutoPairs:
`` let g:AutoPairs={'`': "'", '"': '"', '{': '}', '''': '''', '(': ')', '[': ']'} ``